# Android NOOK Emulator -- bottom of screen is cutoff?

Tags: android, android-emulator, nook

I am successfully debugging my Android app on the NOOK SDK and using the NOOK emulation.  However, I am finding that the lower part of my Nook screen is being cutoff -- I'm talking about the actual screen, not my layout.  Does anybody know how to fix this so the entire NOOK image is displayed in the emulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much experimentation, I found that I can get the whole emulator to display by minimizing it (double click the icon on the taskbar for the emulator), and then click the icon on the taskbar again to re-display the emulator.  After this the complete Nook image is displayed.  It's a little strange, but for now its the best answer I've got.